# Outbound Message For Salesforce Community Actions/Events

Tags: community, workflowoutboundmessage, experience-cloud

Is there any way to tie an event in Salesforce Community for example, a topic created or Level advanced etc. to an outbound message?

I have been looking at the list of objects from which to trigger an outbound message from but I don't see any that jump out as being a community/experience event.

Also, looking at the API endpoints I can't see anyway to extract this sort of data. I wonder am I just missing the nomenclature here for Community/Experience events?

Is the only option here using APEX to pull this data and send on to external systems? I haven't looked into this route as I am not too familiar with it and I am just trying to figure out using outbound messages/REST API prior to passing this on to another team.

Essentially, I am struggling to find the object that is the topic reply/post in Salesforce Experience (se screenshot) and therefore cannot find the topic post or reply via the API or setup outbound messages when a reply is posted for example.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). This site exists to help you to help yourself, so please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/358370/edit) your question to elaborate on exactly *how* you have "been playing around with it" - if it was a Flow or something else declarative, or if it was Apex or something else more code-driven, or if it was multiple different attempts. Whatever it was, please let us know.

Comment: Thanks @Moonpie. I cleared it up a bit above but essentially I am struggling to find the object that is the topic reply/post in Salesforce Experience (se screenshot) and therefore cannot find the topic post or reply via the API or setup outbound messages when a reply is posted for example.

![Screenshot](https://imgur.com/eL8953j)

Comment: Thanks. Please re-edit your question to add the screenshot. Additional information in comments is often overlooked, so it is best to add any pertinent info - whether you originally forgot something , have more to add after additional research or testing, or are adding it in response to someone's question in the comments - to the question itself.